# How to generically handle enumerate(collection)'s different return types for Arrays and Dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, generics, dictionary, swift, each

Being new to swift, as a practice exercise I am trying to write a Swift equivalent to underscore.js' `_.each`:

```
_.each({foo: true, bar: false}, function(value, key) {...}
_.each([true, false], function(value, key) {...}
```

but it is proving difficult since enumerate(collection) returns different types of results for Dictionaries and Arrays:

```
for (indexInt, (key, value)) enumerate(["foo": true]) {...}
for (key, value) enumerate([true]) {...}
```

**How can I handle these two different return types without explicitly checking the generic collection's class for `Array` or `Dictionary`?**

Return type inspection will fail because the following two examples should be treated differently, but return equivalent types from enumerate():

```
for (indexInt, (key, value)) enumerate(["foo": true]) {...}
for (indexInt, (key, value)) enumerate([("foo", true")]) {...}
```

Also, FWIW, $.swift seems to punt on this:

https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift/blob/master/Dollar/Dollar/Dollar.swift#L193-L217

EDIT: Formatting. Also..

**A broken generic implementation**

```
func each<C: Collection>(collection: C, fn: (Any, Any) -> ()) -> C {
    // On next line... Error: Tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'C.GeneratorType.Element'
    for (_, (k, v)) in enumerate(collection) {
        if let innerV = collection[innerK] {
            fn(innerV, k)
        }
    }
    return collection
}
var ret = each(["foo":true, "bar":false]) { println("Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
```

**A working Dictionary implementation**

```
func eachDictionary<K,V>(collection: Dictionary<K, V>, fn: (V, K) -> ()) -> Dictionary<K, V> {
    for (_, (k, v)) in enumerate(collection) {
        fn(v, k)
    }
    return collection
}
var retDictionary = eachDictionary(["foo":true, "bar":false]) { println("Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
```

**A working Array implementation**

```
func each<V>(collection: V[], fn: (V, Int) -> ()) -> V[] {
    for (k, v) in enumerate(collection) {
        fn(v, k)
    }
    return collection
}
var retArray = each([true, false]) { println("Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
```

Edit 2: Updated examples to use overloading. **I'm asking specifically if there is a generic Collection Protocol way to accomplish this without needing one-offs for every Collection type?**

Edit 3: I tried the following (I had to add more typing to the empty array case so it wouldn't complain about parameters to the callback not being printable) but...

1. It fails for dictionaries now (passes `(K,V)` as value)
2. It fails for the `[(V1,V2)]` case
3. I would very much like to find a way to use generics `(K, V)` instead of `(Any, Any)`

Code:

```
func each<C: Collection>(collection: C, fn: (Any, Any) -> ()) -> C {
    for (k, v) in enumerate(collection) {
        if let (key, value) = v as? (Any, Any) {
            fn(value, key)
        } else {
            fn(v, k)
        }
    }
    return collection
}
var ret = each(["foo":true, "bar":false]) { println("1: Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
var arr : String[] = []
var retOne = each(arr) { println("2: Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
var retTwo = each([true, false]) { println("3: Key \($1), Value:\($0)") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enumerate isn't your problem. Dictionary is. What you're trying to do is unlikely to work, because this isn't based on what Collection means. The key in a Dictionary is not related to the integer you pass to an Array. The index of a Dictionary is is a `DictionaryIndex`, not a `KeyType`.

First, let's consider how to write this as a generic function (that doesn't do what you want, but is exactly what you can do on Collection):

```
func each<C:Collection>(collection: C, fn:(C.GeneratorType.Element, C.IndexType) -> ()) -> C {
  for index in indices(collection) {
    fn(collection[index], index)
  }
  return collection
}
```

This walks over the collection and pass its values and indexes to some function that accepts them. For an Array, this function will have the signature:

```
(T, Int) -> ()
```

For a Dictionary, this function will have the signature

```
(ValueType, DictionaryIndex<KeyType, ValueType>) -> ()
```

Your use of `enumerate` is just obscuring this underlying issue. A Collection is a Sequence that returns a value when passed an index via a subscript. That's all it is. A Sequence is something that can generate values via a generator. That's all it is. Between the two, they don't know anything about dictionary keys. A dictionary, from a generic point of view, is just a sequence of key/value tuples.

Now, what you would *like* to be true is that a Dictionary's index were its keys. But it isn't. There's no generic way to discuss a Dictionary's keys, because they're not part of the Collection protocol (and Array and Dictionary share no other common protocol you could hang this on).

So why, you may ask, can you say `dict[key]` and get a value? That has nothing to do with Collection. It's an extra subscript method in Dictionary (comments mine):

```
// This is the Collection subscript
subscript (i: DictionaryIndex<KeyType, ValueType>) -> (KeyType, ValueType) { get }

// This is a subscript unrelated to Collection
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

Since Collection knows nothing about the keys of Dictionaries, a generic solution to this problem is almost certainly impossible.

My suspicion is that the reason Dictionary's key isn't is index is related to the fact that `dict[key]` returns an Optional, while `array[num]` (and generally Collection's subscript) returns the actual value.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the conclusion I've been coming to. Bonus points for using Associated Types in the signature. It seems dictionaries are relatively unique in the Collection context in that their subscript index is not the same as their Collection index. Is there a generic way to extract the subscript index type? It really wouldn't matter if you could, because it's relationship to the value type would be unclear. Many thanks! Sorry, I don't have sufficient karma to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest diffrences between JavaScript and Swift is that you can define (function|method)s with the same name with different signatures (overloading).  Just make use of it.

```
class $ {
    class func map<K:Hashable,V,R>
        (dictionary:[K:V], block:(V,K)->R)->[K:R] {
        var result = [K:R]()
        for (k, v) in dictionary {
            result[k] = block(v, k)
        }
        return result
    }
    class func map<V,R>
        (array:[V], block:(V,Int)->R)->[R] {
        var result = [R]()
        for (k, v) in enumerate(array) {
            result.append(block(v, k))
        }
        return result
    }
    class func each<K:Hashable,V,R>
        (dictionary:[K:V], block:(V,K)->R) {
        for (k, v) in dictionary { block(v, k) }
    }
    class func each<V,R>
        (array:[V], block:(V,Int)->R) {
        for (k, v) in enumerate(array) { block(v, k) }
    }
}

println($.map(["zero":0, "one":1], { n,_ in n+1 }))
println($.map([0,1],               { n,_ in n+1 }))
$.each(["zero":0, "one":1]) { println("\($1) => \($0)") }
$.each([0, 1])              { println("\($1) => \($0)") }
```

Comment: I'm looking for a generic Collection Protocol solution. I could accomplish the same using "each" instead of "eachArray" and "eachDictionary", but I'd have to implement it for every Collection type. The Dictionary vs Array issue is just one failure point, though I'm not sure there is a good solution.